# Highlight highest value in each row for various columns

Tags: excel, vba

I want to highlight cells with the largest value in each row but only using columns F, I, L, O and R.

```vb
Sub Highlights()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ColorRng As Range
    Dim ColorCell As Range
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set ColorRng = ws.Range("F7,I7,L7,O7,R7")
    
    'highlight the cell that contains the highest and lowest number
    
    For Each ColorCell In ColorRng
        If ColorCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ColorRng) Then
            ColorCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 180, 40)
        ElseIf ColorCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(ColorRng) Then
            ColorCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

It works for the first row (that being row 7), but it doesn't continue to the next row. I realize this is because of my `ColorRng` range.

How do I allow the range to include more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try on below sub. As you need to highlight in every row, so you have to iterate every row to compare.

```
Sub Highlights()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ColorRng As Range
Dim ColorCell As Range
Dim lRow As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")
lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

With ws
    For i = 7 To lRow
        Set ColorRng = Union(.Range("F" & i), .Range("I" & i), .Range("L" & i), .Range("O" & i), .Range("R" & i))
        For Each ColorCell In ColorRng
            If ColorCell.Value = Application.Max(ColorRng) Then
                ColorCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 180, 40)
            ElseIf ColorCell.Value = Application.Min(ColorRng) Then
                ColorCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End If
        Next ColorCell
        Set ColorRng = Nothing
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @DavidC If you found it helpful then please mark it as answered. Tick mark it.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this code.

```
Sub SetHighlights()

    Dim ColorRng    As Range
    Dim ColorCell   As Range                ' loop object
    Dim Mini        As Variant
    Dim Maxi        As Variant
    Dim R           As Long                 ' loop counter: rows
    Dim C           As Long                 ' loop counter: columns
    Dim n           As Integer              ' result counter
    
    'highlight the cell that contains the highest and lowest number
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For R = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
            Set ColorRng = Union(.Cells(R, "F"), .Cells(R, "I"), _
                                 .Cells(R, "L"), .Cells(R, "R"))
            Mini = Application.Min(ColorRng)
            Maxi = Application.Max(ColorRng)
            
            For Each ColorCell In ColorRng
                With ColorCell
                    If .Value = Maxi Then
                        .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 180, 40)
                        n = n + 1
                    ElseIf .Value = Mini Then
                        .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                        n = n + 1
                    End If
                End With
                If n = 2 Then Exit For
            Next ColorCell
        Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Observe that the `Min` and `Max` functions are run only once per row instead of for each cell as your original code had it. Turning off `ScreenUpdating` further enhances the speed with which the procedure can complete the job

Answer (score 0):

### Highlight Mins and Maxes

- If error values, it will fail.
- If no numeric value, then no color.
- If max = min, then max color.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub highlightMinMax()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 7
    Const LastRowColumn As String = "F"
    Const ColsList As String = "F,I,L,O,R"
    Dim ColorMin As Long: ColorMin = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' 255
    Dim ColorMax As Long: ColorMax = RGB(0, 180, 40) ' 2667520
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    Dim rgCols As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set rgCols = ws.Columns(LastRowColumn)
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, LastRowColumn).End(xlUp).Row
    If LastRow < FirstRow Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim Cols() As String: Cols = Split(ColsList, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(Cols)
        Set rgCols = getCombinedRangeBasic(rgCols, ws.Columns(Cols(i)))
    Next i
    Erase Cols
    
    Dim rgColor As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim rgMin As Range
    Dim rgMax As Range
    Dim cMin As Double
    Dim cMax As Double
    
    For i = FirstRow To LastRow
        Set rgColor = Intersect(rgCols, ws.Rows(i))
        cMax = Application.Max(rgColor)
        cMin = Application.Min(rgColor)
        For Each cel In rgColor
            If cel.Value = cMax Then
                Set rgMax = getCombinedRangeBasic(rgMax, cel)
            ElseIf cel.Value = cMin Then
                Set rgMin = getCombinedRangeBasic(rgMin, cel)
            End If
        Next
    Next i

    If Not rgMin Is Nothing Then
        rgMin.Interior.Color = ColorMin
    End If
    If Not rgMax Is Nothing Then
        rgMax.Interior.Color = ColorMax
    End If

End Sub

Function getCombinedRangeBasic( _
        ByVal BuiltRange As Range, _
        ByVal AddRange As Range)
    If BuiltRange Is Nothing Then
        Set getCombinedRangeBasic = AddRange
    Else
        Set getCombinedRangeBasic = Union(BuiltRange, AddRange)
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This proposed solution uses `FormatConditions`

- `FormatConditions` will keep the Mins & Maxs updated when ever the values get changed.
- Only need to rerun the procedure when the range changes.
- However, `FormatConditions` are `Volatile` therefore need to evaluate the size of your data.

…

```
Sub FormatConditions_MinMax_NonContiguousRow()
Const kIni As Byte = 7
Dim Rng As Range, rRow As Range, lRow As Long
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")    'Change as required
    
        Rem Disable AutoFilter
        If Not (.AutoFilter Is Nothing) Then .AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter
    
        Rem Set & Validate Last Row
        lRow = .Columns("F").Cells(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If lRow <= kIni Then Exit Sub

        Rem Set Data Range
        Set Rng = .Range("F" & kIni & ":R" & lRow)
        
    End With
        
    With Rng
        
        Rem Delete prior FormatConditions
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        
        Rem Add FormatConditions by Row
        For Each rRow In .Rows
            With rRow
                
                Rem Add FormatConditions Max
                With .FormatConditions.AddTop10
                    .SetFirstPriority
                    .TopBottom = xlTop10Top
                    .Rank = 1
                    .Percent = False
                    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    .StopIfTrue = True
                End With
                
                Rem FormatConditions Min
                With .FormatConditions.AddTop10
                    .SetFirstPriority
                    .TopBottom = xlTop10Bottom
                    .Rank = 1
                    .Percent = False
                    .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 180, 40)
                    .StopIfTrue = True
                End With
    
        End With: Next
        
        Rem Remove FormatConditions from Other Columns
        Application.Intersect(.Cells, Range("G:H,J:K,M:N,P:Q")).FormatConditions.Delete
        .Calculate
       
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]